# Content Resolver .query issues when trying to use where clause

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Probably going to be a complete n00b question with a really simple solutions, but I've got an SQLite db on my app that I am accessing through a content provider.

In one of the activities I am trying to query one of the tables (picturesTable) that contains paths to images and a foreign key to an (itemTable).

I want the query to filter the pictures returned by the itemTable _id field (which is the foreign key saved in the pictureTable.

Whilst testing I am just displaying the returned paths in a TextView. The string `ItemId` is being passed from the previous activity as an intentExtra.

```
    Uri imgUri = mProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] columns = mDbHelper.ALL_IMG_COLUMNS;
    String selection = mDbHelper.IMG_ITEM_ID;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ItemId};
    String groupBy = null;

    Cursor imgCursor = getContentResolver().query(imgUri, columns,
            selection , selectionArgs, groupBy);

    String imgPath = "";
    assert imgCursor != null;
    imgCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            imgPath += imgCursor.getString(
                    imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_PATH)) + "\n";
            imgPath += "Image ID " + imgCursor.getString(
                    imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_TREE_ID)) + "\n" + "\n";
        } while (imgCursor.moveToNext());

    imgCursor.close();
    tv.setText(imgPath);
```

The issue I am having is that currently, its just returning last item in the picturesTable.

If I change `selection` to `mDbHelper.IMG_ITEM_ID + " = ?"`, the app crashes when running.

If I change `selection` and `selectionArgs` to `null`, as expected, I get all of the items returned.

Any advice on what I can do to resolve this would be greatly received, as right now I am going stir crazy!

Comment: @pskink dialogue comes up on emulator "app restarted". Logcat points to the cursor line that is getting the IMG_PATH field.

Comment: dumpCursor is showing all of the expected columns

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely due to an empty cursor being returned as no data matches the WHERE clause.

An empty cursor is distinctly different from a null Cursor which will never be returned by a query. As such the `assert` has no impact for an empty or populated cursor (assuming that is the intention of the assert).

The Cursor's `moveToFirst` method will return false if there is no first row to move to, as in the case of an empty Cursor. However, as this is not being checked an empty Cursor will be treated/handled no differently to a populated Cursor.

As you have `do... while`, if an empty cursor, rather than a populated cursor, exists then `imgPath += imgCursor.getString(           imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_PATH)) + "\n";` will result in an exception due to there being no valid row from which data can be retrieved.

As `moveToNext`, like `moveToFirst`, will return false if the move cannot be made then I'd suggest that the simplest solution to handling no data, at least for this part of the code would be to replace :-

```
assert imgCursor != null;
imgCursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        imgPath += imgCursor.getString(
                imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_PATH)) + "\n";
        imgPath += "Image ID " + imgCursor.getString(
                imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_TREE_ID)) + "\n" + "\n";
    } while (imgCursor.moveToNext());
```

with :-

```
while (imgCursor.moveToNext) {
    imgPath += imgCursor.getString(
                imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_PATH)) + "\n";
    imgPath += "Image ID " + imgCursor.getString(
                imgCursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.IMG_TREE_ID)) + "\n" + "\n";
}
```

This will then not attempt to assign values to **imgPath** for an empty Cursor.

Of course this will not resolve the underlying issue that an empty cursor is returned.